# Linking so file within android ndk

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I'm trying to use openssl within android ndk.

I've used openssl source code from [guardianproject github page](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android/blob/master/README.android), which is able to produce libssl.so and libcrypto.so files.

Currently I'm stuck at linking those 2 files with my jni interface c file.

Below is my Android.mk file, my jni interface c file called "security.c"

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Prebuilt libssl
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/libssl.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Prebuilt libcrypto
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/libcrypto.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := security
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := security.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES= ssl crypto

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And this is my security.c file

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "openssl/bio.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

jstring Java_com_test_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI");
}
```

When build with ndk-build, this error occured

```
    Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in /Users/huydo/cur-project/company/kimisaki_native/android_os/ensemble_girls/AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libcrypto.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : security <= security.c
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libsecurity.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libsecurity.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libsecurity.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libssl.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libssl.so
[armeabi] Install        : libcrypto.so => libs/armeabi/libcrypto.so
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : security <= security.c
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libsecurity.so
[armeabi] Install        : libsecurity.so => libs/armeabi/libsecurity.so
[armeabi] Install        : libssl.so => libs/armeabi/libssl.so
[x86] Install        : libcrypto.so => libs/x86/libcrypto.so
/Users/huydo/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/Users/huydo/cur-project/XXX/android_os/YYY/libs/x86/libcrypto.so'
make: *** [/Users/huydo/cur-project/XXX/android_os/YYY/libs/x86/libcrypto.so] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `/Users/huydo/cur-project/XXX/android_os/YYY/libs/x86/libcrypto.so'
```

Noted that libssl.so and libcrypto.so has been correctly copied into armeabi and armeabi-v7a. It stucked when building for mips and x86 architecture.
If you experienced this error before, can you give me a glue what happened.

Comment: You need to supply a copy of your prebuilt .so prebuilt for each architecture you plan to support.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thanks for comment, you mean supply by rebuild those prebuilt with appropriate flag for mips and x86 (or in another way, my current build of libssl and libcrypto is only support for arm, right)

Comment: from you log.. you seem to be linking x86 traget libssl for arm target .. hence  you have the format mismatch error. try to use arm target libssl.so and libscryto.so files .. it should be no problem .. if could find them.. then recompile your libssl source code for arm target using the arm tool chain in your NDK SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same ARM libssl.so and libcrypto.so when compiling for every architecture, which can't work.

You need to use prebuilts targeting the right architectures. For this you can create subfolders inside *libprebuilt* named against each architecture (*armeabi*, *armeabi-v7a*, *x86*, *mips*), add your prebuilts .so files under each of these, and use *$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)* inside your *Android.mk* to reference your .so files:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Prebuilt libssl
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libssl.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Prebuilt libcrypto
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := security
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := security.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES= ssl crypto

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If you don't find x86 versions of libssl.so and libcrypto.so, you can pull these out from the x86 emulator.

To specify against which architecture you want to compile your projet, use *APP_ABI* variable inside *Application.mk*, for example :
`APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86 mips`